# How to get the groups of a logged in Azure AD user on Windows 10 from C (or any language) code?

Tags: c, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to get the list of groups (by name) that a logged in Azure AD user is a member of.

I know how to do this for a normal Active Directory user, but those methods do not work for an Azure AD user.

Calling NetGetAnyDCName/NetUserGetGroups does not work because the NetGetAnyDCName call with "Azure", "AzureAD", or "Azure AD" fails with ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN. If I query using NULL for the domain, the username is not recognized.

AuthzInitializeContextFromSid (using the SID of the logged in user, intending to call AuthzGetInformationFromContext afterwards) also does not work, returning ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN.

If I use AuthzInitializeContextFromToken with the user's access token from OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess()) and call AuthzGetInformationFromContext(AuthzContextInfoGroupsSids), I new groups (the same number as their Azure AD groups) that do not appear when the user is logged in locally, but LookupAccountSid returns ERROR_NONE_MAPPED and the SIDs, which are 16 bytes do not seem to correspond to the GUIDs assigned to the groups in Azure.

I know this is possible because the Azure Active Directory PowerShell for Graph module has a command (Get-AzureADGroup with no parameters) that will show Azure groups for the logged in Azure user. Calling this tool is not a viable solution to our problem, however, because we would rather not require extra tools to be installed for this to work.

Does anyone know how to this, or (even better) source code in any language that can do it?

Comment: Can you share some details of the workstation and the user that is logged in? More specifically are you referring to W10 that is direct Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined (domain + Azure AD)? Is the user an AD user (with Azure AD presence) or a cloud only user (not represented in AD). Are you trying to determine what AAD groups are in the user's session token or do you literally want to determine what groups in Azure AD a user is a member of? Because if its the latter, it sounds like you need help using MS Graph API using C#.

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp help?

Comment: The workstation is not a member of an AD domain, but the user logged into the machine with an azure AD identity. The user has a local workstation account, but the identity used for Azure AD is completely different ('APeters@somedomain.com' vs 'Alex Peters') so I don't believe the local system will associate them. I want to determine what Azure AD groups the user is a member of. I believe the groups are represented in the user's session token with SIDs that do not have a mapped name (there are two such group SIDs and two groups in Azure AD).

Comment: It's possible the Graph API might be part of the solution. I would still need to figure out how to get whatever security token is required to make a request for the user. My code cannot interact with the user so requesting credentials is not an option (and Get-AzureADGroup returns a list of groups without requiring further input).

Comment: Doing it silently will be impossible if there is no Primary Refresh Token (PRT). If the machine is Azure AD joined this would be easier to do via single sign on using a PRT. I don’t know why they logon using a local account and then use a separate account for azure ad. Would have been easier to make it azure ad joined and logon using azure ad account directly into the machine.

Comment: Hi do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is there any concern?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) should meet your requirement.

Take the official [C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request) as an example.

Microsoft Graph provides two kinds of authorization: [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) and [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0). In your case you should choose [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0).

Then you need to implement [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) and use the the following code to get the groups of the user.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var memberOf = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Here `Me` is the signed-in user.